# Setting timeout on tcp

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

i was wondering if is there any variable that allows me to modifty the value of tcp's timeout. I'm trying to send packages between two virtual machines. 
Thank you.

Comment: do you know how to use ns2 simulator on linux?

Comment: What platform are you working on?

Comment: Which timeout? TCP runs about five of them.

Comment: i didnt know that. I was refering to the one which makes the package resend if there was no ack received

Answer (score 0):

The [`setsockopt` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setsockopt.html) allows controlling a number of configuration parameters, including timeouts.

Comment: i was refering to variables related to tcp like on ipv4

Comment: @user2804422: So was I.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

[Linux increasing or decreasing TCP sockets timeouts](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-increasing-or-decreasing-tcp-sockets-timeouts.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are a load of parameters that you can modify - see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html.

As you question is vague it is difficult to tell you what ones you can modify

Comment: What i am trying to do is to be able to change the default timeout on tcp connection because when you have small loss you can make this variable bigger in order to increase the throughput

Comment: That is not timeout - that is window size. Read the manual page

Comment: not really. The problem when having a big timeout is that if you have any loss, then you will spend a lot of time until you retransmit it. But if i know there is not going to be any loss -or almost- then i can increase the throughtput by incresing this number

Comment: @user2804422: You're confused.  When there are no losses, the retransmission timeout has no effect on throughput.  When there are losses, you want the timeout to be just a little more than the round trip time, so you detect the loss early.  Linux does RTT estimation and already adjusts the retransmission timeout automatically.

Comment: then how can i modify the timeout if i wanted to? i want improve that "automatically adjustment" made by linux in order to get a better transfer time

Comment: @user2804422 - Ben is absolutely right. You can increase throughput be enabling the protocol to have a larger window (i.e. the sending end does not to wait for ACKs so ofter - then more packets in flight)

Comment: i've already done that. now i'd like to increase the timeout because im having too much duplicate ACK.

Comment: @user2804422 - So how does one second guess the transmission time over the internet and not just measure it. Routes/time of day/traffic/.. to consider

Comment: @user2804422 - What exactly is the problem? Have you disabled Nagle?

Comment: @user2804422 - You want to have a timeout that is not measured by the current network traffic. How is that going to work?

Comment: i'm not sure. I was just testing how to improve it. 
I'm trying to reduce the duplicaes ack

Comment: @user2804422 - Why? Is this a problem?

Comment: yes because i want to make it as faster as it can be and im losing lots of time doing this. I'm sending data between two virtual machines in order to get the best time

Comment: @user2804422 - Have you measured this? When not put the two processes on the same virtual machine if this is an issue. Then you can use the loopback address (i.e. 127.0.0.1).

Comment: they're on different vm